# Calling a selectionsort function to sort only a part of an array

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

void selectionsort(int data[ ], size_t n);

How can I call this selectionsort function to only sort a PART of an array? For example, let's say I have an integer ray called intarr with 15 elements. How can I call this function to only sort intarr[3] to intarr[10], for example?

Comment: `selectionsort(intarr + 3, 10 - 3);` Checking for possible off-by-one errors is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function takes a pointer (start) and a length (implicit end).

Figure it out?

Hint: there is no mandate that you have to pass a pointer to the *start* of the array!

Comment: Thank you, just need a pointer to understand this question (no pun intended). First time I'm learning programming before going to college, and definitely not my forte.